# Second ifEmpty condition

Tags: if-statement, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I try to create a second fallback option for the current page. 
My current function get the content of the parent page, if my column is empty. But i also need an option if my fallback is empty too.
It should goes to the next level (leveluid:-3), if my fallback should be empty as well.

Is there any solution to handle this problem with typoscript?

```
variables.element = CONTENT
variables.element {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList.data = page:uid
    orderBy = sorting
    where = colPos=3
  }
  # Fallback
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = CONTENT
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
    table = tt_content
    select {
      pidInList.data = leveluid:-2
      orderBy = sorting
      where = colPos=3
    }
  }
  # Fallback 2
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = CONTENT
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
    table = tt_content
    select {
      pidInList.data = leveluid:-3
      orderBy = sorting
      where = colPos=3
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you do it so complicated?

Either use of CSC or FSC defines `styles.content.get` to gather the content records from the main column (colPos = 0).

this is easy to enhance to other columns and there is an easy mechanism to gather content from pages above: `slide` (see documentation of CONTENT)

```
variables.element < styles.content.get
variables.element.select.where = colPos = 3
variables.element.slide = -1
```